# Deploy the Consul application in Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, consul, hashicorp

As part of our project, we are trying different deployment strategy like k8s, docker and tomcat. We are able to deploy the Consul application in K8s and docker. But we are not able to find a way to deploy the Consul in Tomcat. Is there any options available or anyone have achieved this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because of the technical differences (Consul is written in GO lang). So, it is not achievable for now.

Comment: Could you provide a source proving that?

Comment: @JustSightseeing we have started discussion in this to HashiCorp Discuss itself https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/can-we-deploy-the-consul-application-in-tomcat-server/49099